# Вывод категорий и пунктов меню из разных таблиц БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте. Поставлена задача, вытащить из ДБ некий список с категориями. Имеется 2 таблицы. Первая таблица (menu_categories) хранит категории: id и category_name. Вторая (menu_items) хранит пункты меню: id , номер категории для пункта (item_category) и item_name.

Задача вывести список, в котором по категориям разбиты пункты. То бишь идет первая категория и все пункты, которые относятся к ней, потом вторая и тд.

Сейчас имеется такой вот код. Проблема в том, что с выводом категорий проблем нет, а вот с выводом пунктов в эти категории и возникает вся морока.

```
    $categories_list = mysql_query("
        SELECT id, category_name 
        FROM menu_categories       
    ");

    // получаем все записи из таблицы menu_categories
    while($category = mysql_fetch_array($categories_list))
    {
        echo '<li>'.$category["category_name"].'</li>';
        echo '<ul>';
        // получаем все записи из таблицы menu_item, которые соответствуют категории данного цикла
        $item_list = mysql_query(sprintf("
            SELECT item_name, item_category
            FROM menu_items
            WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT id
                FROM menu_categories 
                WHERE menu_items.item_category = menu_categories.%s
            )
        ", $category["id"]
        ));
        while($item = mysql_fetch_array($item_list))
        {
            echo '<li>'.$item["item_name"].'</li>';
        };
        echo '</ul>';
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запрос:

```
Select c.id, c.category_name, i.item_name
From menu_categories c
Left join menu_items i on i.item_category = c.id
Order by c.id
```

Алгоритм примерно такой:

```
$full_list = mysql_query("
    Select c.id, c.category_name, i.item_name
    From menu_categories c
    Left join menu_items i on i.item_category = c.id
    Order by c.id     
");
$current_c_id = 0;
echo '<ul>';
while($entity = mysql_fetch_array($full_list))
{
    $c_id = $entity["id"];
    if($current_c_id != $c_id)
    {
        if(current_c_id != 0) echo '</ul>';
        echo '<li>'.$entity["category_name"].'</li>';
        echo '<ul>';
        $current_c_id = $c_id;
    }else
    {
        echo '<li>'.$entity["item_name"].'</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul></ul>';
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но сортировка по имени категории зачем? И не подскажете ли, так как вывести в первый проход цикла только, допустим, пункты с item_category = 1? Дальше item_category = 2 и тд?

Comment: Исправил, имелась в виду сортировка по `c.id`, конечно. Для вывода в цикле читаете значение из `category_name` и пока оно не меняется выводите все его `item_name`. Когда `category_name` изменилось - начинаете список для новой категории.

Comment: Алгоритм то понятен (только вот не category_name, а просто id), а вот собственно где проводить это сравнение в коде и как лучше реализовать?  Заранее, спасибо)

Comment: Огромнейшее вам спасибо, очень помогли.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Можете "принять" ответ, если он вам помог.